# Firebase get an specific key

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

i have a `realtime-database` with the following structure:

```
-- test-b7a6b
    -- locations
        -- 0
            -- logs
                -- alarm_2a330b56-c1b8-4720-902b-df89b82ae13a                
                ...
            -- devices
            -- deviceTokens
        -- 1
        -- 2
```

i am using `firebase-functions` that gets executed when a new log gets written

```js
let functions = require('firebase-functions');
let admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendPush = functions.database.ref('/locations/0/logs/{devicelogs}/{logs}').onWrite((change, context) => {
  let logsData = change.after.val();
  loadUsers();
  getBody(deviceTypeId);
  //managing the results
});
```

i have other functions that i want to referenciate to the same location as the one with a new `log`

```js
function loadUsers() {
    let dbRef = admin.database().ref('/locations/0/deviceTokens');
    //managing users
}

function getBody(deviceTypeId) {
  let devicesDB = admin.database().ref('/locations/0/devices');
  //managing devices
}
```

putting the location manually on all 3 functions makes it work just fine but i don't know how to make it listen for the same event on all the locations ( *0, 1 and 2* ) and possibly more locations in the future

So my question: is there a way i can get the location key when a log gets written to any location so i can send it to the other functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To listen to all locations, use a parameter in the path that triggers the function:

```
exports.sendPush = functions.database.ref('/locations/{location}/logs/{devicelogs}/{logs}').onWrite((change, context) => {
```

You can then get the parameters from `context.params` and pass it on:

```
exports.sendPush = functions.database.ref('/locations/{location}/logs/{devicelogs}/{logs}').onWrite((change, context) => {
  let logsData = change.after.val();
  loadUsers(context.params.location);
  getBody(deviceTypeId);
  //managing the results
});
```

Also see the [Cloud Functions for Firebase documentation on handling event data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#handle_event_data).